# Bootstrap checkbox in modal remain checked after closing and reopen again

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I displayed a few checkboxes in Modal for user to choose.

1. user click a button to open a modal
2. user checked 1 or more checkboxes OR uncheck one or more checkbox
3. close the modal without clicking Save button
4. reopen again, the checkboxes are not the original state, its what user has checked or uncheck without clicking Save!!!

What I want is that when user click the modal and reopen again, the checkbox should always show the original checked or uncheck status!

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, Hope it works.

UPDATED

Example at **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/pEoXXR)**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $("#myModal .modal-body").find('input:radio, input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
})
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Have you tried on your computer? I tried using chrome and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and codepen link too

Comment: its weird. It doesn't work for me. How about you copy and paste the full HTML code in codepen.io ? I check and see whats the difference

Comment: My code(HTML + JS) is already there in [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/pEoXXR). You can review it.

Comment: did you put <div class="container"> before modal?

Comment: No container is in my code. You share your code in codepen will help in debug easily.

Comment: that's weird. I put on codepen, it works. but just that my chrome is not working :(    http://codepen.io/gosulove/pen/rrNXLG   .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122584/discussion-between-jyoti-pathania-and-gosulove).